# LM 19 x64 shuts down unexpectedly just before lightdm or cinnamon starts up, because I installed a new battery

Tags: linux, linux-mint, laptop, acpi, battery

LM 19 x64 shuts down unexpectedly just before lightdm or cinnamon starts up. This happens after installing a new battery for my laptop (DELL Precision M4700), and I had to keep the AC adapter plugged in so LM start normally, after that I can unplug the AC adapter.

I tried nomodeset and `acpi=off` with no success. I even downgraded to kernel v4.4.176.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: This looks like problem of the battery itself. It seems, that in peaks, it isn't capable of delivering sufficient power. Have you tried to run some stress test on your notebook (including 3D)?

Comment: I haven't tried any stress tests. But me too I think it is the battery itself causing this issue (I have purchased it from ebay as a generic replacement for my laptop). I think the seller tricked me. I can't return it now because the buyer protection delay has elapsed :(